# Obtaining expressions for functions

Tags: functions

I'm new here, my first post :)  And I am having issues with these questions.  I have explained at the bottom what I have done so far, if you would be able to help me showing the working that'd be appreciated.  I'm really really confused.

If $\displaystyle f(x)= {x\over x-1}$, $x\not=1$, $x \in \mathbb R$,

and $g(x)= 2 - 3x$, $x \in \mathbb R$,

Obtain expressions for the following including their domains.

1) $fg$

*Would I fit $f$ into $g$?  So that means the $g$ would go into the $x$ of each equation?  Could you please help showing working?*

2) $f^2$

*Same as above?*

3) State the domain of $f(t)= t^2 - t - 4$ so that its inverse exists and find an expression for $f^{-1}$ including its domain

Edit: Corrected G

Comment: If you mean $fg$ (without any operation between the functions), then you just multiply $f(x)$ by $g(x)$. Also, $f^2=f f$.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman fg would equal just x/x-1 * x-3x? and ff = x/x-1 * x/x-1? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but @ChristopherCarlHeckman   is incorrect - see my answer

Comment: @tomi : I've always seen composition represented by $f\circ g$, not $fg$.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Alternative_notations

Answer (score 1):

This is about "composing" functions, not multiplying them together. It is a little confusing at first, but OK if you bear this in mind:

$fg$ means $f \left (g(x) \right )$

$f^2$ means $f \left( f(x) \right)$

In your case

1) $fg(x) = f \left (g(x) \right ) =  \displaystyle  {{g(x)}\over {g(x)-1}} =  \displaystyle  {{2-3x}\over {2-3x-1}}$ etc

I've taken this expression another step further - can you take it further?

The domain of $f$ is restricted to $x \ne 1$. This means that in the composed function $g \ne 1$ or $2-3x \ne1$ which is equivalent to $x \ne \frac 13$. You'll see why this is necessary when you see the final expression for $fg$.

2) $f^2(x) = f \left (f(x) \right ) =  \displaystyle  {{f(x)}\over {f(x)-1}} =   {{{x}\over {x-1}}\over {{x}\over {x-1}}-1}$ etc

I've taken this expression another step further - can you take it further?

Here you need to consider restricting the domain twice, because $f$ is applied twice.

First $x \ne 1$.

Second $f \ne 1$. This requires $\frac x{x-1} \ne 1$.

If you consider $\frac x{x-1} = 1$ you get $x=x-1$ which gives $1=0$ - an impossibility, so there is no need to add a further restriction after all.

Comment: Yes!  My apologies.  g:x = 2-3x, x E R.  Can you please help me with these questions by showing the working?  I would REALLY appreciate it as I'm just stuck :(  Especially the last one.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks! would the answer for no 1 be 3x-2/3x-1? @Tomi

Comment: Yes. Attention to notation would save confusion. Composition of functions is notated $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ i.e. do $g$ to $x$ then $f$ to $g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you!  Thus the second answer would be just x ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on the third question.

We have $f(t) = t^2 - t - 4$, which is a quadratic function.  If we [complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), we obtain
\begin{align*}
f(t) & = t^2 - t - 4\\
     & = \left(t^2 - t + \frac{1}{4}\right) - 4 - \frac{1}{4}\\
     & = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4}
\end{align*}
so the function's graph has vertex $(1/2, -17/4)$.

The domain of the function is the set of all real numbers.  Its range is $R_f = [-17/4, \infty)$.  The function $f$ does not have an inverse since for each value of $f(t) > -17/4$, there are two values of $t$ that yield the same value of $f(t)$, as can be seen from its graph.  For example, $f(0) = f(1) = -4$.

[image: graph_of_parabola]

For an inverse to exist, we must restrict the domain so that the resulting function $g(t)$ has one value of $t$ for each value of $g(t)$.  In terms of the graph, this means that a horizontal line should cross the graph of the function at most once (the [Horizontal Line Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test)).

If we want $g(t)$ to have the same range of $f(t)$, there are two ways of doing this.  We can either restrict the domain of $f$ to $[1/2, \infty)$ so that we obtain the right half of the parabola, which yields the function
$$g(t) = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4}, t \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

[image: graph_of_right_half_of_parabola]

or we restrict the domain of $f$ to $(-\infty, 1/2]$ so that we can obtain the left half of the parabola, which yields the function
$$h(t) = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4}, t \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

[image: graph_of_left_half_of_parabola]

Notice that the domain and range of $g(t)$ are, respectively,
\begin{align*}
D_g & = \left[\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)\\
R_g & = \left[-\frac{17}{4}, \infty\right)
\end{align*}

To find the inverse of $g$, we let 
$$u = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4}, t \geq \frac{1}{2}$$
then solve for $t$ in terms of $u$.
\begin{align*}
u & = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4}\\
u + \frac{17}{4} & = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2\\
\sqrt{u + \frac{17}{4}} & = t - \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{u + \frac{17}{4}} & = t
\end{align*}
where we take the positive square root since $t \geq 1/2$.  Hence, the inverse function of $g$ is 
$$g^{-1}(t) = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{t + \frac{17}{4}}$$ 
as you can verify by showing that $g^{-1}(g(t)) = t$ for each $t$ in the domain of $g$ and by showing that $g(g^{-1}(t)) = t$ for each $t$ in the domain of $g^{-1}$.

Observe that the domain and range of $g^{-1}$ are, respectively,
\begin{align*}
D_{g^{-1}} & = \left[-\frac{17}{4}, \infty\right)\\
R_{g^{-1}} & = \left[\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)
\end{align*}
as we would expect since the domain of a function is the range of its inverse and the range of a function is the domain of its inverse.

I leave it to you to determine the domain, range, and inverse of $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Part 3)

An inverse only exists if a function is "one-to-one."

Quadratic functions are "many-to-one" but you can restrict the domain to make the function "one-to-one" over that domain.

So for $f(x)=x^2$, we can stipulate $x \ge 0$ and the function has an inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt x$

In your case, you need to find the minimum point of the function. If the minimum is at $t=a$, then set your domain as $t \ge a$ (although $t \ge a$ would do equally well).

To find the inverse, start by writing $y = t^2-t-4$. Rearrange as $t^2-t-(4+y)=0$ and use the quadratic formula to express $t$ in terms of $y$. Then replace $t$ in your expression with $f^{-1}(t)$ and replace $y$ with $t$.

Worked example:

$f(t)=t^2-6t+7$

Completing the square gives $f(t)=(t-3)^2-2$, so minimum point is when $t=3$. Restrict domain to $t \ge 3$

Rewrite $f(t)=t^2-6t+7$ as $y=t^2-6t+7$

Rearrange to get: $t^2-6t+(7-y)=0$

Quadratic formula gives: $t=\frac {6 + \sqrt{9-4(7-y)}}{2}$

Note that I have only added because we have restricted the domain.

$t=\frac {6 + \sqrt{9-28+4y}}{2}$

$t=\frac {6 + \sqrt{4y-19}}{2}$

Replace to get: $f^{-1}(t)=\frac {6 + \sqrt{4t-19}}{2}$

Comment: Why not just complete the square on $f(t) = t^2 - t - 4$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  I didn't want to confuse the questioner, but yes, that was my first thought.